# How to insert a number to every cell of a cell array in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a cell array like this:

```
    a = {[1 2 3]; [4 5]; [6 7 8 9]};
```

and want to insert, for example, 10 to the beginning of every cell to have this:

```
    >> a{:}

    ans =

        10     1     2     3

    ans =

        10     4     5

    ans =

        10     6     7     8     9
```

Is it possible to do it without any for loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [CELLFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) with anonymous function:

```
b = cellfun(@(x)[10 x],a,'UniformOutput',0)
```

---

To answer @tmpearce comment I used a simple script to measure running time:

```
a = {[1 2 3]; [4 5]; [6 7 8 9]};
tic
a = cellfun(@(x)[10 x],a,'UniformOutput',0)
toc
a = {[1 2 3]; [4 5]; [6 7 8 9]}; 
tic
for ii=1:numel(a)
    a{ii} = [10 a{ii}];
end
toc
```

The results:

```
Elapsed time is 0.002622 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.000034 seconds.
```

Comment: This does avoid loops, though it might be worth checking if there's a speed benefit over a simple loop - cellfun/arrayfun are often very slow

Comment: a comparison on such a minuscule data is almost meaningless