# Matlab: arrayfun, cellfun, spfun and structfun vs. simple for-loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

Which one is better, using all the `*fun` functions (`arrayfun`, `cellfun`, `structfun` and `spfun`) or simply using `for` loop?

What method gives better performance and which methods should be considered better practice in terms of readability of the code?

Comment: Related question: [arrayfun can be significantly slower than an explicit loop in matlab. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522888/arrayfun-can-be-significantly-slower-than-an-explicit-loop-in-matlab-why)

Comment: also related [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15181321/1714410)

Comment: I'd say that it depends quite a lot on which MATLAB release you are uging. In my case, MATLAB R2012a, I'm making use of almost only `for` loops

Comment: I'd say that the relative performance of various ways of computing functions over arrays changes as Matlab is developed and that it behoves the professionals among us to (re-)test our thinking about which approach is faster with each new release.  As for readability of code, that's very subjective and I fear to tread there.

Comment: for-loops are currently the most optimized constructs by the JIT acceleration. The hope is that arrayfun/cellfun/.. will be automatically parallelized sometime in the future

Comment: for instance, MATLAB currently has [arrayfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/arrayfun.html) that runs on the GPU for `gpuArray`. Octave has a [parallel arrayfun](http://octave.sourceforge.net/general/function/pararrayfun.html) using multiple processes on the CPU (sort of the equivalent of `parfor`)

Comment: another related question with comparisons: [What is the fastest way to perform arithmetic operations on each element of a cell array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851718/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-perform-arithmetic-operations-on-each-element-of-a-ce)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It really depends on what you call 'performance' :)

If you mean *minimum execution time*, well, sometimes `*fun` are faster (for example, `cellfun('isempty', ...);` (yes, string argument!) for sure beats the loop version). Sometimes a loop is faster. If you're on a Matlab version < 2006, go for the `*fun` functions by default. If you're on anything more recent, go for the loops by default. You'll still always have to profile to find out which one's faster.

As noted by Amro, if you have a GPU capable of doing FP arithmetic, and a recent version of Matlab that supports GpGPU, then a call to `arrayfun` for `gpuArray` inputs will be massively-parallelized. However, no general statements can be made regardnig execution time; for smaller arrays, or absolutely humungous ones, the overhead of copying everything over to the GPU might undo any benefit of parallelizing the computations, so...profiling is really the only way to know for sure.

If you mean *minimum coding* time, then I'd say it's usually faster to code in terms of `*fun` as long as the operations are simple. For anything complex it's usually better to go for the loop.

If you mean *optimum readability* and thus *minimum time required for maintenance and implementation of changes in a professional context*, for sure, go for the loop.

At this point in time, there's not really a clear-cut simple answer to your question :)