# Summing a cell array?

Tags: matlab

I have a function that takes in any number of arguments into a cell array

```
function sumThese(varargin)

subtotals = cellfun(@sum, varargin);
total = sum(subtotals);

disp(total)
end
```

This works for arrays and numbers, except as soon as I have a square matrix it doesn't. It'll tell me:

> Non-scalar in Uniform output, set 'UniformOutput' to false.

However if I set `'uniformoutput'` to `false`, I get this error now:

> Undefined function or method 'sum' for input arguments of type 'cell

How to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the function `@sum` in the `cellfun`

```
subtotals = cellfun( @(x) sum(x(:)), varargin );
```

**Why?**
becuase the output of `sum`, when applied to a matrix is no longer a scalar what turns `subtotals` into a cell array of scalars and vectors, instead of a 1D vector.

Use debugger to see the difference.

PS,
Did you know that [`cellfun` is not always better than a simple loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143314/matlab-arrayfun-cellfun-spfun-and-structfun-vs-simple-for-loop).

**EDIT:**
A solution using `for` loop:

```
total = 0;
for ii = 1:numel(varargin)
    total = total + sum( varargin{ii}(:) );
end
```

Comment: Thanks that works! Can you give me a hint on how to loop through it?

Comment: One follow up, what if one of the arguments is a cell array? Then sum won't work on it since it is type cell...

Comment: @rawrrang and what if there are `NaN`s in some of the cells? and what if there are strings/chars? You should know your inputs... If the inputs are very complicated you should replace the simple `sum` function with something more sophisticated that you'll write that can handle all these special cases...