# deleting empty rows in a cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I have a cell array `(10001x21)` in which the first 3 columns have data in all the rows. From columns `4 to 21` I have data In some of the cells of a particular row and some rows might be completely empty.

I want to retain only rows which have the data in some of the columns from `4 to 21`  and remove all the empty rows which do not have any data in the columns `(4:21)`. Any help would be appreciated in this case.Thanks.

**This is in Matlab environment**

This is how the data looks

'1Fb6'  2014    'F' []  []  []  []  []  []  []  []  []  []
'1Fc6'  2014    'F' []  []  []  []  []  []  []  []  []  []
'1Fd6'  2014    'F' []  []  []  []  []  'ka1'   []  []  []  []
'1Fk6'  2014    'F' []  []  []  []  []  []  []  []  []  []
'1Fy6'  2014    'F' []  []  []  []  []  []  []  []  []  []
'1Fz6'  2014    'F' []  []  'na1'   []  []  []  []  []  []  []
'1Fj6'  2014    'F' []  []  []  []  []  []  []  []  []  []
'1Fm6'  2014    'F' []  []  []  []  []  []  []  []  []  []
'1Fn6'  2014    'F' []  []  []  []  'bo1'   []  []  []  []  []

Comment: In what environment?

Comment: umm... what programming language?

Comment: what kind of data? Can you provide a small example?

Comment: i just added the data.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that your cell array was called `data`, with dimensions `[rows, columns]`. You can retain only all rows that have some data in columns 4:21 in a new matrix called `new_data` using this code:

```
new_data = data(~all(cellfun('isempty', data(:, 4:21)), 2), :);
```

To break this down:

- `cellfun('isempty', data(:, 4:21))` returns a matrix of size `[rows, columns-3]`. Any empty cells in `data` from columns 4:21 are labeled 1, and all other cells are labeled 0.
- `~all(cellfun(...), 2)` returns a vector of size `rows x 1`. It takes this previous matrix and sees if each row is a cell array of all 1's (in other words, if this row is completely empty). The `all` function returns true if the row is all 1's. However, because of the NOT operator (~), all rows with only 1's are actually labeled 0, and all other rows are labeled 1. In other words, the rows labeled 1 are the rows that we wish to keep.
- `new_data = data(all(...), :)` simply returns the data matrix, deleting any rows that are completely empty in columns 4:21.

Comment: You can [remove that `find`](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/). Also, `'isempty'` [may be](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/42335-array-cellfun-vs-for-loop) [faster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143314/matlab-arrayfun-cellfun-spfun-and-structfun-vs-simple-for-loop) than `@isempty`

Comment: @Luis Mendo Thank you for mentioning these tips. Edited my answer.

Comment: @It's Magic - This worked .Thanks a lot.i tried doing this before dtc_final_1(all(cellfun(@isempty,dtc_final_1(,4:21)),2),:)=[].This was not doing the job.